# How can I call an angular controller function from my custom polymer web component?

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I've seen this question and seen it answered but not in any way I can use or understand.  The question is very specific and simple but somehow the answers are a bit over my head.

All I want to do is have a very simple menu work.   when i menu item is clicked, I need it to of course use my angular controller function to handle it.  I want all of that on the angular side.  It actually does work when I simply use the elements directly without declaratively making my own.

So this works just fine and my ng-click is successfuly calling my acceptedSelect() in my controller:

```
<core-menu>

        <div  ng-repeat="order in acceptedOrders" ng-click="acceptedSelect(order)">

            <paper-item class="my-paper-item" >
                <div class="order-list-item">
                    <div class="order-number">{{order.Order}}</div>  
                    <div class="order-date"> {{order.Date}} </div>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    <div class="order-address">
                        {{order.Property}} 
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </paper-item>
        </div>
    </core-menu>
```

But i do the same thing by wrapping the paper element in a polymer-element, it doesn't work.  So this will not work:

```
<polymer-element name="my-app" attributes="refresh">

<template>
    <style>    
   ...
</style>
 <core-menu>

    <div  ng-repeat="order in acceptedOrders" ng-click="acceptedSelect(order)">

            <paper-item class="my-paper-item" >
                <div class="order-list-item">
                    <div class="order-number">{{order.Order}}</div>  
                    <div class="order-date"> {{order.Date}} </div>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    <div class="order-address">
                        {{order.Property}} 
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </paper-item>
    </div>
</core-menu>
</template>
<script>  
      Polymer('my-app', {                                    
        });
```

```
<my-app></my-app>
```

I'm just not sure what I can do to make this work.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add the links to the questions you think are similar.